# Calculating the percentage of factors on a integer

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to calculate some basic training calculations. For that i have a dataset with the age of people and smoking habits.

```
'data.frame':   725 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Age      : int  6 18 16 14 5 11 8 11 15 11 ...
$ Smoke    : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Now i want to create a table, which shows me the range of age, and the percentage of the people who are smoking.

```
table(Age, Smoke)
Smoke
Age  no yes
10 47   4
11 50   8
```

So similar to this, but with percentages to yes and no, like this:

```
Smoke
Age  no yes
10 0.91 0.085
11 0.84 0. 16
```

Is there a simple command for this? I just could do it with a lot of manual assigning etc.

Comment: try `prop.table()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `prop.table`:

```
prop.table(table(Age, Smoke),1)
```

Note that `1` stands for `margin = 1` - that is, you want row proportions. If you don't specify a margin, you will get proportions relative to the whole table.

See also:

```
?addmargins
?ftable
```